# can I crop the map in Composer?

Tags: qgis

I need a map that is tall & narrow--4" wide by 8" tall. However, when I try to drag the boundary between the Layers Panel and the map view, it will only go a certain amount. I cannot drag the boundary beyond a certain point, so the map view remains too wide. Then when I bring the map into Print Composer, it includes that same full width. Is there a way to crop the map in Composer, or somehow create a view that is tall & narrow?

Here is a screenshot showing the view panel as narrow as I can make it.
[image]

Comment: A screenshot example my help.

Comment: Crop in composer? Do you mean portrait orientation instead of landscape?

Answer (score 5):

The link between the canvas and the composer is weak, so you can make all the adjustment in the composer while keeping a pleasant display in the canvas.

Open the composer, add your map, set the scale (1), then adjust the map size (2) and pan the map content to fit properly (3)

[image]

Comment: Thanks JGH; but after I set the scale; then when I adjust the map size as you suggest, it changes the scale. It does not change the area of land that is included. Even if I drag a side handle, rather than a corner one, the whole thing shrinks when I drag it in. Is there a way to freeze the scale and only crop off areas along the sides?

Comment: To clarify: I want the whole area shown, top-to-bottom. However, I do not want to include an inch or so along each side. I need to show an area that is relatively long north-to-south, but only a short distance east-to west. I cannot make the map view area that shape in the main program. So then when I import the map view into Print Composer, it shows extra areas along the sides. And I can't find a way to crop out the areas I don't want, while retaining the whole range north-to-south.

Comment: @TVZ you can then set the exact extent rather than the scale. You should do it after having resized the map container.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to explicitly designate the extents of the map window in the composer map frame, once you determine exactly what you want in the composer frame (balancing desired scale, space available in desired sheet size, etc.).

[image: Map Extents]

I often actually create a rectangle polygon layer in the Map Window with the same proportional dimensions as the target composer map frame, and can display that in the Map Window when I need to visualize what will be in the composer frame.  You can also query the extents of that rectangle to provide the extent values to use in the composer map item (cut and paste from Vertex Editor when selecting Node Tool in edit mode).

[image: Composer Layout rectangle]